# AppleScript Set Name of File

Tags: applescript

I am having an issue with the following AppleScript code:

```
repeat with index from 1 to jpgCount
    set currentFile to item index of jpgList
    if index is less than 10 then
        set numberPrefix to "000"
    else if index is less than 100 then
        set numberPrefix to "00"
    else if index is less than 1000 then
        set numberPrefix to "0"
    else
        set numberPrefix to ""
    end if
    set fileNumber to numberPrefix & index as string
    set the name of currentFile to "2021_0514" & "_" & fileNumber & ".JPG"
end repeat
```

I get an error highlighting the line `set the name of currentFile to "2021_0514" & "_" & fileNumber & ".JPG"`, which is strange because it normally works fine.

The error says:

error "Finder got an error: Can’t set alias "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Desktop:SourceFolder:TestFile001.jpg" to "2021_0514_0001.JPG"." number -10006 from alias "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Desktop:SourceFolder:TestFile001.jpg"

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have not provided enough _code_ for us to reproduce the error. Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then add the relevant _code_ for us to reproduce the error.

Comment: The error -10006 either means `errAEWriteDenied` or `errOSACantAssign` which both could mean that you don't have write access. I could be wrong though and I will be digging deeper into this.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments, your code is not enough to reproduce the error, but I guessed what you could be trying. I added 3 lines of code to the top which are:

```
set this_folder to (choose folder with prompt "Pick the folder containing the images to process:") as string
tell application "System Events" to set jpgList to every file of folder this_folder
set jpgCount to count of jpgList
```

It worked perfectly for me so. As already stated in the comments, error -10006 either means `errAEWriteDenied` or `errOSACantAssign` which both could mean that you don't have write access.
Problems could involve:

1. You are not the admin of the machine
2. You are trying to access a folder that doesn't belong to the active user
3. In all your errors it states that you tried to access the path "Macintosh HD:Users:UserName:Desktop:SourceFolder:". If you changed your real name to UserName for this post, this shouldn't be a problem though.